# jQuery ajax code inside "success" function only works if placed first

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I'm experiencing some extremely weird behavior with Ajax. Or maybe it's normal. I wouldn't know. I'm quite new to playing around with Ajax.

My problem is that I am making a few Ajax calls(two using `$.post()` and one using the standard `$ajax()` call), and they seem to return the data fine, but the code inside the success function only works in a very peculiar way.

I have noticed that some things work if placed first in line to be executed; but why is that?   It really doesn't make any sense to me. In this case I would like the span with the id link_span to be updated dynamically, as my Ajax calls link and unlink devices from each other. 
(the correct_classes function counts how many links have been linked and adds it to the link_counter variable that I've made global with the window object).
But as the span only wants to update if the corresponding code is placed on top, it's kinda useless.

Another problem is also that `.ajaxComplete()` and other such event handlers don't always get called. For example, I attempted to show and hide a loader gif by using `.ajaxComplete()` to close it when ajax stop. But this only works with one of my calls which is the standard `$.ajax` call.

I'm really confused.

Any help would be great, and please ask me to clarify if there's something I haven't made clear enough.

Here is a small snippet of what I'm talking about:

```
$.post( "<?php echo base_url(); ?>connections/ajax_link", datax).done(function( resp,status ) {

    $("#loader_overlay").css('display','none');
    display_confirmbox(); 
    resp=JSON.parse(resp);

    var str = resp['parent_selector'];
    var arr = mystr.toString().split("||");
    correct_classes(arr[1], resp);

    $( '#link_span' ).text( '( ' + window.link_counter + ' ) links found' ); //this doesnt work unless its on top
});
```

**Update**

It seems that the problem is caused by `correct_classes()`; 
the array from the ajax call gets passed to the function in which jQuery complains about something, and causes the rest of the ajax code to halt. Yet everything inside `correct_classes()` gets executed. The error in question is this:

`TypeError: invalid 'in' operand e`

specifically what is causing the problem seems to be this(i commented everything else out and this is:

```
  $.each( val, function( i, value ) {
    var mystr = value;
  }
```

I really cant figure out why it complains about this code when it seems to work.

Comment: by 'on top' you mean as the first instruction in you done handler functions?

Comment: Yes. First in line, first to be executed... i honestly don't know the proper term

Comment: Then does maybe `display_confirmbox()` interfere with `$( '#link_span' )` in any way (ajax call maybe?)

Comment: no. display_confirmbox simply contains:
        $( '.x1' ).css( 'visibility' , 'visible' );
        $( '.x2' ).css( 'visibility' , 'visible' );

Even so, if there's something that can interfere with an ajax call, how do I find out what that is? I have been trying to find info on this, but no luck so far.

Comment: Well, you should place a break point at that line and inspect what's going on at that particular time. It can be a JS error at some line before that would interrupt the execution...

Comment: It seems that there is indeed an error caused by correct_classes which stop the rest of the code from executing... Which is strange :-/ it does exactly what it's supposed to.

Comment: Have some error in console??

Comment: "TypeError: invalid 'in' operand e" 
And gives me a bunch of jQuery code. basically what its complaining about is this inside my code:                                 `$.each( val, function( i, value ) {
      var mystr = value;}); `

However there rest of the code inside works fine. I just need what's inside mystr to split it into an array of two items.

Comment: `invalid 'in' operand e` this error i think was throw because `val` in the each method isn't an object or an array... write a console.log before: `console.log(typeof val)` -> this return the type of val... if isn't "object" (like null, string, boolean) there are something gone wrong before. Maybe JSON parse (because you not define dataType in some call)

Comment: How about that! you were right, Frogmouth :) I hadn't really thought about this, so thank you! This is probably something I should be attentive for in the future as well. It fixed the weird "stopping in the middle of everything" problem in my ajax call :)

Comment: ah that's nice! I'm glad to have helped you! :) it's every time a pleasure!!

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure to have understand your problem.... but if you use 3 async ajax call ($.post or $.ajax is indifferent $.post is a contract syntax to call $.ajax({type:"post"})) you need to wait the full loading of all calls for use their response.

so.. if one of your call evalue **window.link_counter** you need to wait his response before call the code you have post.

For wait the complete load you may nast the call inside the success function of the prev call.

for you knowlage there is an attribute of `$.post()` **dataType** if you set it to `"json"` you not need to parse the response because Jquery do it for you, this code is useless:

```
resp=JSON.parse(resp);
```

and, the method `.done()` is calling whether the call is successful if it fails, `$.post()` has a success function callback. Use it, it's better, and use `.fail()` to catch call error.

See documentation about $.post(): [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

however... the element who have this id `#link_span` is generated by one of ajax call?

Comment: All calls happen separately. I modified my ajax call to use the success callback instead of the .done handler and added the json datatype, however the problem remains the same. Somehow jquery is annoyed with what Im trying to do, yet the rest of the code works.
the #link_span element is generated in another ajax call that happens initially.